# Javascript to fully open dialog before loading content

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript that displays a hidden div in a dialog, the hidden div holds a TimyMCE instance. My problem is I can’t type into the TinyMCE text area, it’s locked or something. I think the problem is the dialog needs to fully load before loading TinyMCE, I guess so that TinyMCE is on top of everything.

Can I edit this code so that collorbox has fully loaded before loading TimyMCE inside quictEditPanel?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#quictEdit").colorbox({
        width: "740px",
        inline: true,
        href: "#quictEditPanel"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, you should *always* use the jQuery [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#quictEdit').colorbox({
        width:"740px",
        inline:true,
        href:"#quictEditPanel"
    });
});
```

Comment: By using `$(document).ready()` function you're actually making sure jQuery has been loaded. And only then you can use the `$(…)` syntax.

Comment: Yep, so in my case this is not the issue!

Comment: If you have copied/pasted your code as is, it is a major mistake you're making. There can be additional issues, nevertheless.

Comment: Just worked out it almost works perfectly in IE. the only thing that doesn't is that I have to hit a key on the keyboard before the text appears. This kind of proves the test is there to begin with!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you call the element ID before the dom load, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quictEdit").colorbox({
      width: "740px",
      inline: true,
      href: "#quictEditPanel"
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Someth, iv'e tried that and many other ways but I still cant type in the box, something is blocking it. Everything else on the form works, even every thing else in TinyMCE, just not the box. This was a stab in the dark that it maybe the problem but now it seems like it's not.